# Thread dump and memory dump makes sense only at particular point of time?

Tags: java, performance, debugging, thread-dump, memory-dump

As per my understanding, a Java thread dump is the dump of all threads depicting what every thread in the JVM is doing  or state of each thread 
at a specific point of time. Similarly, a memory dump represents the health of memory at a specific point of time.

Does any tool provide a way to take a memory or thread dump of an hour or more so that if I want to analyze the state for an hour I can do that?

I don't see any way of doing it in jconsole, jvisualvm, or dynatrace. Maybe there is a way but I am not finding it?

Comment: What kind of state would you be wanting to extract?

Comment: I would say you can't have "_**the** state for an hour_" ... you can have a (very long) sequence of states, with a different state being added to the list every time (almost) anything changes.

Comment: It might help to explain what problem you're trying to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the memory dump: Dumping memory regularly would need one really, really big and very, very fast filesystem. So no, I woudn't advise on doing that. Better to define some triggers based on gc activity or other conditions.

Regarding the Stack-Traces: If you face race conditions, phases where your (heavily multithreaded?) application freezes or slows down for all users, I've found it helpful to collect a few (3-5) thread dumps with 3 to 5 seconds offset in regular intervals (we started off with 5 min and as system grew more stable cut it down to 30m) and then compare these snapshots to each other identifying possible interference.

While the first iterations involved jstack, it later evolved to JMX based access to the java application and pulling database lock info at the same time.

So your question can be answered with a heartily: "It depends". Memory dumps should be pulled only if you see `OutOfMemoryError`s. Thread dumps can be useful at times when there might be high traffic / freezes / thread congestions.

Comment: And though you can't do continuous memory dumps, memory analysis tools will typically be able to calculate the delta between two heap dumps taken for example an hour apart.

Comment: @biziclop maybe you can advise on tools that can do that? For me analyzing at point of OutOfMemory worked out so far, so I have no experience on those.

Comment: @Jan when you sa `, I've found it helpful to collect a few (3-5) thread dumps with 3 to 5 seconds offset in regular intervals (we started off with 5 min and as system grew more stable cut it down to 30m) and then compare`  does it mean that you have taken 3-4 time dumpa at different point of time. Right ?

Comment: @Jan Can jstack pull database deadlock info also ?

Comment: @Jan I'd rather not, because every tool does it in a slightly different way. But both visualvm and MAT are capable of it.

Comment: No, database lock we did on our own. That's way we moved away from jstack - we wanted a snapshot of all systems involved in the transactions. Note it's *lock* not **deadlock**, because deadlocks, as nasty as they are, don't kill your app, because the DB will detect those.

Comment: About the intervals: Think of it as a strobe - short, fast flashes. We did dump-dump-dump and then compared the three dumps taken shortly after each other. Threads that did not move (showed same stack trace) were analyzed in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is periodically dump the memory / threads state, I don't know of any tool that can do that but it should be pretty easy to write your own implementation.

For thread dumps you can use [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html), and [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) for heap dumps. Both are part of the standard JDK's.

Keep in mind that saving lots of heap dumps can easily use up all your disk memory. Also, I am not sure that thread dumps over a long period are useful. As far as I know they are often used to inspect the stacks at a specific time frame to find errors / deadlocks etc.

Comment: i agree with your statement `As far as I know they are often used to inspect the stacks at a specific time frame to find errors / deadlocks etc` Is it true for memory dump too ?

Comment: Memory (heap) dump is typically used for investigating memory leaks. I often use `hprof`s automatically generated by the VM once out of memory errors occurs (it is possible to turn this option on) to find the leak.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Javamelody but you will need to 'add' it to  your application.

https://github.com/javamelody/javamelody/

It allows you to monitor you application and see history, as well as to generate dumps (but I don't think it can give you a dump between two events in the past)

Answer (score 0):

If you want complete memory dump, then you have to go for heap dump (jmap -F -dump:live,format=b,file= ) which is not recommended in a production system (Jan has already pointed out). However, there are other ways to keep an eye on the memory usage in a regular fashion without impacting the performance of the production system :

1. > jstat -gc Process_ID 300s

This will capture overall memory usage and garbage collection details every five minutes. However, it will not tell you which object is consuming how much of memory etc (which is captured by the heap dump). However, if there is a memory leak, you will be able to find out over time.

2. > jmap -histo Process_ID

This will generate the histogram information for the application. Write a script and invoke it once in every _ minutes.

If #1 and #2 shows symptoms of memory leak, then only go for a heap dump, but it may "hang" your application and you may have to restart it just after capturing the heap dump.

As far as thread dump is concerned, if you want to regular monitor thread state, you may use the following. I am familiar with applications where they do it every 5 minutes and store data for last 7 days.

> jstack Process_ID

or (with Java 8)

> jcmd Process_ID Thread.print

During abnormal situation, you can always capture 5/6 thread dumps every 10 seconds.

Or if you (or your company) can afford and you want regularly keep an eye on the system you may look for [New Relic](http://newrelic.com) kind of softwares.